# Filter specific element from JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a function where I'm using API and I dispay JSON

What I want, it's to filter only some specific element in JSON and not all element
How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help

```
function getAllIssueForSCII(){
        var options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '***',
            headers: {  
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': "***"
            }
        };

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            request(options, function (error, response, data) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log('JIRA login success!!')
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(json); // display all element JSON
                    resolve(json);            
                } else {
                    console.log('error: ' + response.statusCode + ': ' + data.statusMessage)
                }

            })
        })
```

Actual result :

```
{
  expand: 'schema,names',
  startAt: 0,
  maxResults: 50,
  total: 2,
  issues: [{
      expand: 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
      id: '59032',
      self: '**',
      key: 'SCII-10',
      fields: [Object]
    },
    {
      expand: 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
      id: '59028',
      self: '**',
      key: 'SCII-7',
      fields: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
  issues: [{
        key: 'SCII-10',
        fields: id: 1
        name: toto
        time: now
      },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I need to use the method filter ?

Comment: How do you plan to filter it? i.e., based on what criterion?

Comment: You've already parsed the JSON to an object, so could you just navigate to those items in the object? Are those properties always going to in same structure?

Comment: You can directly get *issues*.  according to your code, you can use `json.issues`

Comment: Oh, are you wanting to map the issues array to a new array who's objects only have the expected key/value pairs?

Comment: Yes I know that I can navigate items in the object. When I parse data, I don't want parse all element because some I'm not using all element. I just want to use elements who are in the part "Expected result"

Comment: Well, you wouldn't gain any performance advantage trying to cut out parts of the file before you parse, you'll just create a new object from the parsed one, and if you're really worried, you can de-scope the json variable after you've created your new object from it/

Comment: Are you expecting the issues array to have more than one entry such that you'll need to map 'issues' to a new object/array?

Comment: Oh ok because I'm doing this for gain any perfomance ...

Comment: Parsing it to an object is how you filter it... The only way to cut it down before parsing it would be to parse it; perhaps with a different parser but still parsing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```js
const response = { expand: 'schema,names', startAt: 0, maxResults: 50, total: 2, issues: [ { expand:  'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', id: '59032', self: '**', key: 'SCII-10', fields: {} }, { expand: 'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields', id: '59028', self: '**', key: 'SCII-7', fields: {} } ] };     

let filterId = '59032';
console.log("Filtered Issues: ", { issues: response.issues.filter(issue => issue.id === filterId ) });
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Danmoreng mentioned in his comment you just need to navigate your JSON.

I guess you are new to javascript let me show you :

```js
var jj = { expand: 'schema,names',
startAt: 0,
maxResults: 50,
total: 2,
issues:
[ { expand:
        'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
    id: '59032',
    self: '**',
    key: 'SCII-10',
    fields: [Object] },
    { expand:
        'operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields',
    id: '59028',
    self: '**',
    key: 'SCII-7',
    fields: [Object] } ] } ;

    var expected_output = {}; // we declare an empty object
    expected_output.issues = []; // we declare "issues" a new field in our object 
    expected_output.issues[0] = {}; // we first element of our array is an object
    expected_output.issues[0].key = jj.issues[0].key; 
    expected_output.issues[0].fields = [];
    expected_output.issues[0].fields = jj.issues[0].fields;
    console.log(expected_output);
```